# Cannot pass Facebook Android App publish_actions review

Tags: android, facebook

I have submit the publish_actions review for an Android App. I have checked all the necessary options and uploaded a screen-cast of our demo.

After one week, it doesn't pass the review. The message is:

Your screencast doesn't show how this permission is used in your app, and we weren't able to reproduce the permission on our end either. Please upload a new screencast and update your submission notes before you resubmit. Learn more about making and submitting a screencast.

So I updated the screencast and uploaded it again. But after 20 days, the review result is still the same as before. It is not updated. How many days does it take to pass the review. For me, it is too long.

Comment: The review will take on average 24 hours. At worst it is 5 business days. If you waited more than that you never submitted again. Or there is a bug that you should file at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: How can we find out our bug? Our purpose is to let user to share a photo to Facebook. So we use publish_actions. Notes: We use ShareSDK to realize this feature, not the native Facebook API document.